# Laravel mutators on specific situations

Tags: laravel, mutators

As I understand, mutators change your attribute on save function (create or update). Can I make mutator just for atrribute display to users, but leave default values on save function ?

Comment: It's called an accessor: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eloquent Model when you do this:

```
public function getSomeNameAttribute($value)
{
    return ucfirst($value);
}
```

That ^ will mutate the value for showing it later in views and it won't affect what is stored in DB table.

And also if you use a setter `setSomeNameAttribute($value)` you can pull the actual value from db table with:

```
$model->getOriginal('attribute_name'); // Laravel V. ^5.*
```

or

```
$model->getRawOriginal('attribute_name'); // Laravel V. ^8.*
```